# Build Systems for Embedded Linux

Tags: jenkins, embedded-linux, build-system

I work on a device that uses Embedded Linux. In the near future this device is going to probably turn into a product family and a few more devices (i.e. hardware platforms) are going to added to the mix. These devices will be similar but may have processors, hardware peripherals (and device drivers), user space applications and kernel settings. In addition to compiling distributions for different devices, I'd also like to build debug distributions for development.

What are some of the more common ways to assemble and manage Embedded Linux systems? I have been playing around with Jenkins some and see some potential there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several build systems targeting Embedded Linux:

**[OpenEmbedded](http://www.openembedded.org/index.php/Main_Page)**

**[Buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/)**

**[Scratchbox](http://www.scratchbox.org/)**

**[PTXdist](http://www.ptxdist.org/software/ptxdist/index_en.html)**

**[LTIB](http://www.bitshrine.org/ltib/)**

**[Emdebian](http://www.emdebian.org/)**

There is document which compares them [here](http://free-electrons.com/pub/conferences/2008/ols/celf-bof/). But I suppose the **Buildroot** is the most famous and used among [them](http://free-electrons.com/docs/buildroot/). There are more interesting docs related to Embedded Linux on free-electrons.com.